# Eclipse create runnable jar problem

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

Ok I created a new Java project in Eclipse with Java class and its main method.  Then when doing an export - runnable jar I do not see my new project being listed in the "Launch Configurations" drop down.  I can see other projects but not the newly created one.

I'm I missing something?

```
public class SSLTest {
   public static void main(String[] args)  {
}
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Did you run `SSLTest` in Eclipse?  I think you need to run that class (through the Run menu) in order for Eclipse to create a launch configuration.

Comment: +1 Yup, you need to create a launch config in order for it to be available to export.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Run as-> Run as Java Application your java file having main class.
There you go -> Now you can see your project listed in "Launch Configurations" when you try to export as runnable jar file.

Comment: This was the key for me. The configuration was not available as I was always running my class as a TestNG test. Once I ran it as a Java Application I was able to see the launch configuration when exporting to jar.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse there are different categories of run configurations. "Eclipse Application" configs can't be used to create runnable jars. You need to have a "Java Application" configuration.

Answer (score -1):

In Eclipse, under the file tab, choose runnable jar file under java folder, fill in information, u need a launchConfig and then u can save it

Good Luck!